# Select n random rows for each language ID in one table

Tags: mysql

I have a table which holds many text entries for many languages, the structure is like this:

```
`entry` varchar(255),
`language` tinyint,
```

The `language` column is an integer type and I have the supported languages pre-defined in my code like `LANG_EN = 1, LANG_DE = 2` etc, so I know the maximum possible value.

I want to select **only** one random row for **each** supported language ID, preferably with a single query.
So if I have 3 supported languages, the query should return 3 rows, with unique `language` values, therefore having one entry per each language.

I tried it a few ways, with using DISTINCT and GROUP BY but couldn't get it working with a single query.

`SELECT * FROM lang_entries GROUP BY language ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3`

This selects 3 entries of each language, but always the first occurrences in the table (meaning that only the order is random, the `entry` field is 
always the same and that's what I want to be random)

`SELECT DISTINCT lang, entry FROM test ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3;`

This kind of works, but doesn't select unique items, sometimes the languages are repeated and I need to have distinct languages.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, may be:

```
select language, 
(select entry from entries e1 where e1.language = e.language order by rand() limit 1) entry
from (select distinct language from entries) e
```

[dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c1701e0c383cdaeab22a664b6ad8d61)

Comment: And change `LIMIT 1` to something larger -- for the Title request of "select N random rows".

Comment: @RickJames Quoting the OP, "_I want to select only one random row for each supported language ID_". The title seems misleading.